# cakephp - Save file syncronized and send as attachment

Tags: cakephp

Hi have a strange problem with File::write() in cakephp.

I write this code to generate a pdf view and save it on a file.

```
private function generate( $id ){

    $order = $this->Order->read( null, $id );
    $this->set('order', $order);

    $view = new View($this);

    $viewdata = $view->render('pdf');

    //set the file name to save the View's output
    $path = WWW_ROOT . 'ordini/' . $id . '.pdf';
    $file = new File($path, true);

    //write the content to the file
    $file->write( $viewdata );

    //return the path
    return $path;

}
```

I need generate this pdf and send it as attacchment so, this is my code

```
public function publish ($id) {
    $pdf_file = $this->generate( (int)$id );

    $Email = new CakeEmail();
    $Email->from(array('info@.....com' => '......'));
    $Email->to('....@gmail.com');
    $Email->subject('Nuovo ordine');

    $filepath = WWW_ROOT . 'ordini/' . $id . '.pdf';

    $Email->attachments(array('Ordine.pdf' => $filepath));

    $Email->send('......');

}
```

The first time i run this code the email doesn't works, the email works nice only if the pdf is alredy in the folder.

I think that File::write perform some kind of async writing and when system execute Email::attachments the file ins't ready.

How can i insert a while() in this code to check file avability?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($file->write( $viewdata ))
{
   return $path;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using the return value wasn't enough.
I changed this line

```
$file = new File($path, false);
```

Opening file without forcing worked for me.